# Unable to show icon after showing menu Items in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have created a dropdown for the icon where when the icon is clicked, it will show the dropdown. Once we hover on Card then the three dots icon will appear. But my objective is even after showing dropdown the icon should appear. but here is my code, it is disappearing. Can anyone help me with this query?

Here is the code:

```
    <Card>
        <CardHeader
          className={classes.header}
          avatar={<Avatar aria-label="recipe">R</Avatar>}
          action={
            <div>
              <IconButton
                id="simple-menu"
                className={classes.showIcon}
                aria-label="settings"
                aria-controls="simple-menu"
                onClick={this.handleClick}
              >
                <MoreVertIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Menu
                style={{ marginTop: "35px" }}
                id="simple-menu"
                keepMounted
                anchorEl={this.state.menu}
                open={Boolean(this.state.menu)}
                onClose={this.handleClose}
              >
                <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>change password</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
              </Menu>
            </div>
          }
          title="Shrimp and Chorizo Paella"
          subheader="September 14, 2016"
        />
      </Card>
```

[Here is the sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-feynman-hn7ce)

Comment: are you talking about those 3 horizontal dots?

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi - HI, Yes, I'm talking about the dots icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a style className which sets the icon visibility to `visible`. Conditionally assign the class to the parent div only when the menu is open i.e. check for `this.state.menu && classes.menu`.

**Style**

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  header: {
    background: "grey",
    "&:hover": {
      background: "yellow",
      "& $showIcon": {
        visibility: "visible"
      }
    }
  },
  showIcon: {
    visibility: "hidden"
  },
  menu: {
    "& $showIcon": {
      visibility: "visible"
    }
  }
});
```

**JSX**

```js
<Card>
        <CardHeader
          className={classes.header}
          avatar={<Avatar aria-label="recipe">R</Avatar>}
          action={
            <div className={this.state.menu && classes.menu}>
              <IconButton
                id="simple-menu"
                className={classes.showIcon}
                aria-label="settings"
                aria-controls="simple-menu"
                onClick={this.handleClick}
              >
                <MoreVertIcon />
              </IconButton>
  ...
```

[Working copy of your code is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-menu-button-visibility-fix-96hnq?file=/src/Sample.jsx)

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot, This Solution works great :). Thanks for helping

Comment: Hi, facing a small problem after applying this code. Could you help me in solving the problem?